Всем заголовкам в тексте добавить атрибут id
Есть текст, хранится в переменной $text, внутри встречаются заголовки . Нужно на php добавить к каждому из них атрибут id по порядку. Например, должно получиться:
<p>Бла-бла-бла</p>
<h2 id="id-1">Заголовок первый</h2>
<p>Бла-бла-бла</p>
<p>Бла-бла-бла</p>
<h2 id="id-2">Заголовок второй</h2>
<p>Бла-бла-бла и т.д.</p>

Вот что написано на данный момент:
    $regularka = '/(.*?)<\/h2>/i';
$matches = array();     
preg_match_all( $regularka, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );
$i=1;
foreach ($matches as $elm) {
$text = str_replace('<h2>', '<h2 id="id-'.$i.'">', $text);
$i++;
}   

Но в таком случае ко всем заголовкам прибавляется id-1

Данные у вас в matches... в $elm, а работаете вы с $text.

@АлексейШиманский ну мне же вроде как в $text надо записать потом обновлённый html-код статьи?

В данном случае надо использовать preg_replace_callback
$text = '<p>Бла-бла-бла</p>
<h2>Заголовок первый</h2>
<p>Бла-бла-бла</p>
<p>Бла-бла-бла</p>
<h2>Заголовок второй</h2>
<p>Бла-бла-бла и т.д.</p>';

$regularka = '/(.*?)<\/h2>/i';
$matches = array();     

$i = 1;
$result = preg_replace_callback($regularka, function ($matches) use (&$i) {
    return str_replace('<h2>', '<h2 id="id-'.$i++.'">', $matches[0]);
}, $text, PREG_SET_ORDER );
        
echo $result;        


Но вообще, я бы рекомендовал библиотеку для работы с DOM, например https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php
Это правильный вариант разбора HTML и замены информации в узлах

Теперь присваивает порядковый id только первым двум заголовкам, а остальным не присваивает вообще никакого id

Это неправда https://onlinephp.io/c/a42ab   .... А если хочется прям точной точности, то, как я писал, надо использовать нормальную библиотеку, а не парсинг регулярками

Это правда. Если Вы здесь  onlinephp.io/c/a42ab добавите в исходный текст ещё один заголовок, то на выходе у него не будет id. Я только что проверил. Насчёт библиотеки спасибо, попробую.

Я скажу так: проставление идентификатора абсолютно всем заголовка на странице - бестолковая задача не имеющая никакого смысла. У задачи должно быть обоснование. Например добавить идентификатор всем заголовкам для каждой статьи... Но даже в этом случае это бестолковщина, т.к. им нужно проставлять всем общий класс, а не идентификатор... Так что для начала надо определить смысл задачи и исходить из неё. На данный момент это сферический конь в вакууме. И поэтому при новых миллионах вводных данных конечно надо всё менять будет. Возможно, банально, регулярка не работает как надо (что не удивительно)

Смысл задачи - по заголовкам формировать автоматически оглавление статьи, с якорями. Само оглавление я сделал, а теперь нужно присвоить айдишники заголовкам внутри статьи. На них ссылаются пункты оглавления. PS Регулярка по всей видимости работает, т.к. с её помощью я сформировал оглавление. Код оглавления не привожу: там создаётся отдельная переменная в отдельном цикле.

Окей, тогда значит надо убрать , PREG_SET_ORDER из кода

И регулярку скорее всего надо писать так: '/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>/i' - это как-то более логично

Спасибо, убрать PREG_SET_ORDER помогло
